# Magento white screen

Tags: magento2, memory

One of my pages suddenly became white screen as I was working on the code. It was working perfectly and it won't go back to normal even when I revert the change.

Every other page is working fine,the problem is just with one page.

**I tried increasing the memory limit.(first to 1G and now to -1),still no change.**

Could someone help me out?

My index.php

```
_DIR_ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
  \/* @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
try {
    require _DIR_ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<


        Autoload error

    {$e->getMessage()}

HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/* @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app /
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: add this to index.php `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`. Then refresh the page. this will show you the error on screen. it's not a solution, but a place to start

Comment: I did,but didnt display any errors,I will post the code of my index.php below

Comment: What is the mode developer/default/production?

Comment: Check webserver logs, white screen should leave concrete error there